# tailwind config build tools in monorepo

Tags: build, config, tailwind-css

So we want to start a new project having a monorepo with every component as a separate project.
i.e.

```js
App (repo)
-- Button (project)
-- -- package.json
-- Radiobutton (project)
-- -- package.json
tailwind.config.js
```

What we'd want to do is having a single tailwind config and be able to have a build per component run through the main `package.json` in App. So that we minimize the css classes left in `Button` for instance.

Basically a css class should be generated for `Button` containing only the classes used there.
Similarly it would happen for `RadioButton` having everything completely separate.

Has anyone got an idea of an approach to this?
I can find info on monorepo's but not in combination with tailwind specific covering multiple projects given that we don't want to have a config file in each project.

Output would then be:

```js
dist/App
-- Button
-- -- Button.jsx
-- -- Button.css
-- Radiobutton
-- -- Radiobutton.jsx
-- -- Radiobutton.css
```

Comment: confused what you are trying to achieve, but from what I can tell, you shouldn't need any tailwind config in each component,  only the the deployable package needs it, and you'd have to configure postcss to look through all the packages when working what css to kill

Comment: I basically want every component to have its own trimmed css file, not one large one. This is for reuse purposes in other projects across the company.

Comment: We did eventually settle for SCSS with a custom build script to generate the css in every monorepo. However we ran into problems rather quick with scalability because of components using other components in the same project and bloating the css generated that way. We now generate a single css file from all the small scss files inside of all the projects through scss and include that once.